# Problem with word filter using discord js, code gives no output

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So this is the current code I have for the word filter. I have an array of the censored words in a JSON file. Whenever I try to run the bot and type in a swear word I get no response and no error msgs in Powershell.
I'm quite a beginner so excuse any mistakes and excuse the train wreck of a code this is. Just trying to learn.

```js
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const { wordFilter} = require("./filter.json");

const {clientId, guildId, token, prefix} = require('./config.json');

const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({ intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
] });

const fs = require('fs');

const giveMeaJoke = require('discord-jokes');


client.commands = new Discord.Collection();    

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./Commands/").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./Commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}



 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is now available!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {


    const command = message.content;

//Profanity Filter
if(message.author.id = "909209531811242044"){
    return
}

let foundinText = true;
for(const word in wordFilter){
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(wordFilter[word].toLowerCase())) foundinText = true;
}
if(foundinText){
    message.delete();
    message.reply('Be polite, no swearing please');
}
// End of profanity Filter

    if(message.content == 'Hello')message.reply("Hello!");

    if(command == prefix + 'Ping'){
        client.commands.get('Ping').execute(message, command);
    }


    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
    if(message.content.toLowerCase()==  prefix + 'hello'){
        message.reply('Hello!');

    }if(command == prefix + 'Website'){
        client.commands.get('Website').execute(message, command);
    }

    if(message.content.toLowerCase()== prefix + 'joke'){
        giveMeaJoke.getRandomDadJoke(function(joke){
            message.reply(joke);
        });
   
    }




});



client.login(token);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as a codeblock, not an image

Comment: Done, added my block of code as text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to reduce the number of steps in your procedure. Ensure `wordFilter` is a string array.

```js
const hasProfanity = wordFilter
   .some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()));

if (hasProfanity && message.author.id !== '909209531811242044') {
    message.delete();
    message.reply('Be polite, no swearing please');
}
```

This is one of many ways to check for words, but it has it's issues. For example if the word "ass" is a keyword, the word "assure" would checkout and `hasProfanity` would equal `true`

A better method would be to first split `message.content` by a space into an array and check each individual word.

```js
const words = message.content.split(/ +/);

const hasProfanity = words
   .some(word => wordFilter.includes(word.toLowerCase());

// Remaining Code
```

It's best if the words in `wordFilter` are all lowercased, this way you don't have to call `.toLowerCase()` on them on each iteration